# Forcing early-z with raytracing

Tags: glsl, depth-buffer, culling, raytracing

I'm working on a GLSL raytracer, and I need to be able to edit gl_FragDepth in the FS.  However, doing so disables early-z culling.  The scene is rendered front-to-back and the FS can only push points further away, so the results of the z-test shouldn't affect the final render, even with a long pipeline.

Is there anyway to force early-z culling to run, or otherwise get around the "no fragdepth" restriction?  I suppose I could do a z-test in the FS, but I'd rather let the hardware take care of it if possible.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is called "Conservative Depth". There is an AMD OpenGL extension at least: [GL_AMD_conservative_depth](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/conservative_depth.txt) But there is also a DX11 semantic which I have used in the past and works on both vendors, although it is poorly documented. It's described here on [slide 81](http://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC-2010/pdfs/2157_GTC2010.pdf).

As for OpenGL on NVIDIA, I'm not sure. There is GL_ARB_depth_clamp, but I don't think that will help with your situation.

EDIT: Oops, looks like AMD_conservative_depth has become ARB_conservative_depth since I last looked. So you should be good to go for most cards.